# Rails + Geocoder: undefined method `search' for Geokit::Geocoders::Geocoder:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I am playing with the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), I added this code to **user** model

```
  include GeoKit::Geocoders

  geocoded_by :full_street_address   # can also be an IP address
  after_validation :geocode          # auto-fetch coordinates
```

and in a different controller, in the **CarController#index** I am calling:

```
zip_code = '94301'
aaa = Geocoder.search(zip_code).first.coordinates
puts '==='
puts aaa.inspect
puts '==='
```

But instead of

```
s[0].latitude   # =>    37.4457966
s[0].longitude  # =>    -122.1575745
s[0].address    # =>    "Palo Alto, CA 94301, USA"
```

I got

```
undefined method `search' for Geokit::Geocoders::Geocoder:Class
```

What's incorrect with the setup of Geocoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its just a namespace issue. You need to remove `include GeoKit::Geocoders`. I looked in [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) source and can't find anything GeoKit

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geocoder-1.1.8/lib
$ find . | xargs grep -i GeoKit
$
```

So I googled and apparently there's another gem called [geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit). The namespace you've mentioned gets resolved in this gem at [line 92](https://github.com/geokit/geokit/blob/master/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb). And this GeoCoder class obviously doesn't have a search method. So I suspect you've a reference to geokit in your Gemfile.

And btw I use just geocoder & it works fine on my environment -

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p247 :001 > zip_code = '94301'
 => "94301"
2.0.0-p247 :002 > aaa = Geocoder.search(zip_code).first.coordinates
 => [37.4457966, -122.1575745]
2.0.0-p247 :003 >
```

Comment: Ye, you were right man. In the system were snippets of an old code that contained **geokit** gem. Thanks a lot!